Emotionally and professionally unavailable
Is there a phrase to describe a person who is emotionally unavailable to commit?

"emotionally unavailable" is psychological jargon dating from before the second world war, which made its way into public discourse in the 1960s and 1970s.   What sort of phrase are you looking for?  An idiom?

Have you looked this up online and in dictionaries? What have you found so far?

You question is unclear as in the title you ask about emotionally and professionally unavailable yet the body of your question only asks about those who are emotionally unavailable.
I agree with TimR's comment that 'emotionally unavailable' is exactly the phrase you're looking for when considering your question from the body. As for the question in the title, for someone to be both emotionally and professionally unavailable you'd be looking at a term like aloof:

Aloof: not friendly or willing to take part in things


Alternatively Aloof: not interested or involved, usually because you do not approve of what is happening

Definitions from Cambridge
This combines the emotional aspect of 'emotionally unavailable' but isn't so specific as to preclude it also being applied professionally. There is the limiting factor that there is an implied, active, disinterest in the person or thing this individual is aloof towards. For this reason you may consider not reinventing the wheel and stating plainly how this person is unavailable, for example:

Steven sat there, staring into space across the office, emotionally unavailable, even in a professional sense.

Edit: correcting grammar
